# Why does it show none at the end? Once i call the main function? How does the code need to be improved to not have it show none at the end?

Tags: python, function

Once i call the main function I get none at the end. How does the code need to be improved to not have it show none in the end of the function call.
[def count_spaces, then call main function to count number of spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0oEa.png)

Comment: You're printing the result of `count_spaces()`, but that function does not contain a `return` statement, therefore it returns `None` by default, therefore `None` is printed.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and information as **text** in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Function returns None without return statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/7053652); you are using `print()` in two places, and don't return anything from your function. Either remove the `print()` printing what your function returns (which is `None`) or remove the `print()` call in the function and use `return` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the result of the `count_spaces` function. That function does not return anything (well, actually, a function that doesn't return anything returns `None`).

So when you do `print(count_spaces())`, you are printing `None`.